# Convert CSV to JSON key value

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
First Name*,Registrarse
Last Name*,Registrarse
Your Email*,Nombre*
Country*,Apellido*
```

I am looking for someway to convert this to JSON like this:

```
{
  "First Name*": "Registrarse",
  "Last Name*": "Registrarse"
   .....
}
```

I tried NPM tools like CSV to JSON and I could not get this effect.
Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the CSV file into an associative array and encode that as JSON:

```
$csv = <<<EOF
First Name*,Registrarse
Last Name*,Registrarse
Your Email*,Nombre*
Country*,Apellido*
EOF;

$csvArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);

$jsonArray = array();
foreach ($csvArray as $row) {
    preg_match('/(.*?),(.*)/', $row, $matches);
    $jsonArray[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
}

$json = json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
{
    "First Name*": "Registrarse",
    "Last Name*": "Registrarse",
    "Your Email*": "Nombre*",
    "Country*": "Apellido*"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Coming a bit late into this thread but in case it interests some other future user. I created a tiny in-browser app able to handle that.

Just go to [csvtojson.com](http://csvtojson.com) and paste your csv, it will be output to you as needed.

Comment: the site is offline

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, here is another link: http://csvtojson.netlify.com